# Concat two SQL's Results in one Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have the following table "Custumer":

```
Customer_ID     Customer_Name

01               John
02               Mary
03               Marco
```

I would like to return the following result from a select:

```
Query_Result

01
02
03
John
Mary
Marco
```

Is it possible? Merge both columns in one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way (assumes Customer_ID is a character type)

```
SELECT 
   Customer_ID
FROM Customer

UNION ALL

SELECT 
   Customer_Name
FROM Customer
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `UNION ALL`, the following should work for you.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(30), Customer_ID) FROM Customer
UNION ALL 
SELECT Customer_Name FROM Customer
```

Comment: Even though varchar length is 30 characters when using with `CONVERT` function, as a good practice you should always explicitly define the length.

Comment: `Customer_ID` already appears to be a `VARCHAR` type (it has leading 0's).  Also, as @Kaf pointed out, it is a good practice to specify the length when converting.

Comment: @Kaf and @Jon Thanks, fixed the `varchar` size and I used `CONVERT` because there was no indication in the OP's question if the `Customer_ID` field was a NUMERIC or varchar data type.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have two options to achieve this:

1. Select data from each column and use `UNION ALL` to merge results. Be careful to make sure that the results of each select produce the same data type.
2. Unpivot table as on example below:

   ```
   SELECT AnyColumn
   FROM
   (SELECT Customer_ID, Customer_Name
       FROM Customer) p
   UNPIVOT
   (
       AnyColumn FOR Customer IN
       (Customer_ID, Customer_Name)
   ) AS unpvt;
   ```

Personally, I would question necessity of doing such operation. If you find yourself to be forced to do it, I'd recommend you re-think your data model.